# Unable to recover windows password

Tags: windows, password-recovery

Last week I lent my laptop to my kid brother and he changed my password (Password of the only admin account in the PC) , and now i am lock out of the laptop and he says he doesn't remember what he changed the password into. How can I get access in to my laptop.
The laptop is an Dell Inspiron 13 running Windows 10

Comment: Enable the built Administrator and reset the password on the account

Comment: How do I enable the built in administrator?

Comment: See duplicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download a light OS (I usually use Ubuntu)
2. Use a ISO burning software (Microsoft Rufus) to copy ISO file to a USB drive
3. Boot using the USB drive
4. Press 'Try Ubuntu' option
5. Open file explorer
6. Open HDD containing system files
7. Go to Windows\system32
8. Rename Sethc.exe to Sethc.old
9. Copy and paste cmd.exe to same directory and rename to sethc.exe
10. Restart computer (boot to windows HDD) after removing USB drive

11.Once the logon screen opens press repeatedly press shift until cmd opens

After following the steps choose method 1 or 2

**METHOD 1**

12. Type "net user" on CMD. And it will give the names of the users on the computer ( I will use Jaffer as the username on following command)
13. Type "net user Jaffer XXX"
14. Close CMD and type XXX as password

**METHOD 2**

12.Type "net user administrator /active:yes" And restart PC

13. Login to the new administrator account without password
14. Goto Control panel and remove password of the other account